# how to suppress crystal report page footer when month column have not more then 1 month

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

im setting up crystal report to suppress the page footer when column dont have multiple months.

**not suppress Crystal report pages footer** 
31/07/2019
31/08/2019
30/09/2019

**suppress crystal report pages footer** when only 1 month
31/07/2019

Answer (score 0):

1] create a summary for that field and then Suppress it.

2] Now go to the Section Expert and write formula for Suppress.

3]

```
 if summary column (select this from reports field) > 1 then true 
        else false
```